# How to find the nth value in a Fibonacci series?

Tags: python, fibonacci

```
# Function for nth Fibonacci number 

def Fibonacci(n): 
    if n<0: 
        print("Incorrect input") 
    # First Fibonacci number is 0 
    elif n==1: 
        return 0
    # Second Fibonacci number is 1 
    elif n==2: 
        return 1
    else: 
        return Fibonacci(n-1)+Fibonacci(n-2) 

# Driver Program 

print(Fibonacci(9))
```

I am new to programming.
I cant get how this codes finds out the Fibonacci number....
How does the program calculates the value of (n-1) and (n-2)

Comment: Try 0 as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your program uses recursion.

Here you can find visualization, which could help you with understanding:
https://observablehq.com/@victormutai/visualizing-recursive-fibonacci-algorithm

Alternative implementation is iterative algorithm. I could be easier to understand

```
def f(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
```

Comment: Can you tell me something about how recursion works..

Answer (score 1):

Here is an illustratory diagram from **the [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html) book**.
[image]

When `Fibonacci(5)` is invoked, `Fibonacci(5-1)` (`fib 4`) and `Fibonacci(5-2)` (`fib 3`) are invoked in return. When `Fibonacci(4)` is invoked, `Fibonacci(4-1)` and `Fibonacci(4-2)` are invoked in return, so on and so forth. This is called a *recursion*.

Finally, when either `Fibonacci(2)` or `Fibonacci(1)` is invoked, its result `1` and `0` is returned directly without further invocation. It is the termination conditions of such recursion.

By the way, as is depicted in the diagram, the multiple times' invocations of `fib 3`, which is seen as repeated calculation, result in inefficiency. So it is only for demonstrating how recursion works while usually not used to calculate fibs in practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
return Fibonacci(n-1)+Fibonacci(n-2)
```

This is a recursion. You should cache values to reduce recalculation.

moreover, there is Binet's formula to calculate it at O(1) time.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind that piece of code is **recursion**. Have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) to find out more about it.

Answer (score 0):

To explain how your code works to identify the nth number in the Fibonacci series, first you need to understand how a Fibonacci series is generated.

0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, and so on.

Here if you look at the first two numbers it is 0 and 1, these are the base numbers, from there on the next number is found out by the addition of the previous two numbers. Hence the formula.

```
F(1) = 0
F(2) = 1
F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)
```

Now if you look at your code the above is exactly depicted here. Any value of n less that 1 will be considered as invalid. A value of 1 returns a 0 and a value of 2 returns a 1. this is exactly the same as we have mentioned above.

```
Fibonacci(n-1)+Fibonacci(n-2)
```

Finally for all other cases we find the previous two numbers in the series by using the same rule(function) and sum them to get the desired number.